# PostCSS dynamically generating classes using mixins

Tags: javascript, mixins, postcss

I am trying to dynamically generate a bunch of classes using something like this `@mixin generateTextColourClasses gray, --gray, 3;`

which would produce the following

```
.text-gray-100 {
    color: var(--gray-100);
}

.text-gray-200 {
    color: var(--gray-200);
}

.text-gray-300 {
    color: var(--gray-300);
}
```

I have the following code which is a custom js mixin which is defined as

```
    'postcss-mixins': {
      mixins: {
        generateTextColourClasses: function (mixin, name, variable, step) {
          for (let i = 1; i < step; i++) {
            var rule = postcss.rule({ selector: '.text-' + name + '-' + i + '00' });
            rule.append({
              prop: 'color',
              value: 'var(' + variable + '-' + i + '00)'
            })
            mixin.append(rule)
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

However, there are no classes in the generated css file. I suspect its the final part `mixin.append(rule)` but I can't find the right solution using http://api.postcss.org/AtRule.html